# How exactly is a distribution function of a probability density function calculated?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Elementary statistics student here. How exactly is this question solved? I have looked up many sites and videos and each one solves questions like this one in a totally different way.

Q. Find the distribution function of the pdf

$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{1c} 2x, & 0≤x≤1 \\ 0, & otherwise\end{array}\right.$

Edit:

What I don't understand in the question is this:

How can the interval be $0≤x≤1$? I mean if this is a pdf, then this means that continuous random variables are involved, which then means that the random variable x can never be $exactly$ zero or one. So shouldn't the range be $0<x<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$f(t)=\left\{ \begin{array}{1c} 2t, & 0≤t≤1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right., 
$$
a probability density function. Find the (cumulative) distribution function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where 
$$
F(x) =\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt.  
$$

$\color{green}{\text{Let }x<0}$. 
Then 
$$
\color{green}{F(x)} =\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt =  \int_{-\infty}^x 0 \: dt =\color{green}{0}.   
$$
$\color{magenta}{\text{Let }0\leq x \leq 1}$.
Then 
$$
\color{magenta}{F(x)} =\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^0 0\: dt +  \int_{0}^x 2t \: dt =0 + t^2\bigg|_{t=0}^{x} = 0 + (x^2 -0^2)=\color{magenta}{x^2}.  
$$
$\color{blue}{\text{Let }x>1}$. Then 
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{F(x)} &=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt \\ 
&= \int_{-\infty}^0 0\: dt +  \int_{0}^1 2t \: dt + \int_1^x 0 \: dt \\
&= 0 + t^2\bigg|_0^1 + 0 \\ 
&= 0 + (1^2-0^2) + 0  \\ 
&= \color{blue}{1}.  
\end{align*}
So the (cumulative) distribution function is 
$$
F(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
0 &\mbox{ if } x < 0,  \\ 
x^2 &\mbox{ if } 0\leq x \leq 1, \\ 
1 &\mbox{ if } x > 1. 
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

In general, for a density function $f$, the (cumulative) distribution function $F$ is given by
$$
F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt
$$
Since your $f$ is defined by cases, chances are your $F$ will be too. It's even probably a good idea to calculate that integral for three different cases, depending on whether $x<0,0<x<1$ or $1<x$.

Of course there are other ways to solve it, but why is that a bad thing? If you can manage to learn several of them, then you are that much better equipped to handle trickier problems in the future.

Comment: I don't understand how the question is solved. Calculating the cumulative distribution for a pmf -the one with discrete variables- was clear, but I am very confused with calculating it for a pdf.

Comment: I have just told you how: you integrate.